# SQL-Print column name based on value and condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to print column names based on condition and value.
My problem is this
If two all the columns in the two rows like for data x and y have value `yes` the it should print those column names otherwise not

My code:

```
select 'A' from world.city where A = 'yes' AND data=y and data=x union all
select 'B' from world.city where B= 'yes' AND data=y and data=x  union all
select 'C' from world.city where C= 'yes' AND data=y and data=x  union all
select 'D' from world.city where D= 'yes' AND data=y and data=x  union all
select 'E' from world.city where E= 'yes' AND data=y and data=x;
```

It is not giving perfect results.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What results are you getting?

Comment: "It is not giving perfect results."  What results does this query give? And what results do you expect?

Comment: You should post text, not images. Anyway, you didn't ever ask a question. Please check the Help Centre to learn how to do so.

Comment: Please, don't add images to your question. Add it as formatted text. It is way better to us to use it to create a test case and help you out.

Comment: @underscore_d They asked in the image: "What do you think?"

Comment: OK. so let me rephrase... They never asked any question *in the text*, and even *in the image*, they asked a question so vague that it can't be answered.

Comment: Looks like you are storing the data the wrong way around. This problem would be simple with a transposed table (where X, Y, and Z are columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a sum and union all then filter the rows with sum('yes') is equal to 2. See below.

```
select colname 
from (
select 'A' as colname,sum(case when A='yes' then 1 else 0 end) col
from tbl where data in ('X','Y')
union all
select 'B',sum(case when B='yes' then 1 else 0 end)  
from tbl where data in ('X','Y')
union all
select 'C',sum(case when C='yes' then 1 else 0 end)  
from tbl where data in ('X','Y')
union all
select 'D',sum(case when D='yes' then 1 else 0 end)  
from tbl where data in ('X','Y')
union all
select 'E',sum(case when E='yes' then 1 else 0 end)  
from tbl where data in ('X','Y')) tab
where col = 2;

Result:
colname
B
D
```

Comment: Can you please explain that what is `colname`, `col` and `tab`

Comment: colname is the column name alias I use for the result. B and D are columns in your original table. While col is also an alias to the sum of 'yes' in each column A B C D E and F. Then tab is an alias for the table that I created in UNION all.  MYSQL is strict in subquery and it requires a name for the subquery.  Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!